# What should I do to call audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:

Tags: objective-c, ios, exc-bad-access, avaudioplayer

I wrote this source program .  But I can't call *audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:* method.
After playing the sound, which crashes by "exc_bad_access" error after a few seconds.

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController<
AVAudioPlayerDelegate>{
    AVAudioPlayer *aPlayer;
}
@end
```

.m file

```
-(void)playSound{

NSString *soundName = @"red";
NSError *error = nil;
NSURL *soundUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:soundName withExtension:@"mp3"];
aPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:&error];

if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"audio_player initialized error :(%@)",[error localizedDescription]);
    [aPlayer release];
    error=nil;
    return;
}

NSLog(@"player Ok!");
aPlayer.delegate = self;
[aPlayer prepareToPlay];
aPlayer.volume=1.0f;

[aPlayer play];

}
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{
[player release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use that works perfectly, it should help you.

```
-(void)playSound{

    NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"red"];
    NSString *source = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"mp3"];
    if (data) {
        [data stop];
        data = nil;
    }
    data=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: source] error:NULL];
    data.delegate = self;
    [data play];
}
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)data successfully:(BOOL)flag{
    NSLog(@"my log");
    [data release];
}
```

Comment: ...and it went wrong because you declared your AVAudioPlayer as "aPlayer" and then called "player" in your audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying method.